# Moss CO2 consumption

Tags: botany, photosynthesis, plant-anatomy

I wish to calculate how much CO2 would a sq m of moss fixes to glucose in one day, taking about 20 degrees C average temperature, 55% humidity and a regular 8 hour day. Water and nutrients are at optimal amounts. Is there a formula I could use? I can't seem to find anything online.